# Database password without special characters problem in 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to host a site in 000webhost, while creating a database the password generated is not accepted by the db.php file in my repo, its been throwing

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /storage/ssd4/844/14839844/public_html/db.php on line 7
```

But I am unable to create a password without special characters, I am unable to connect my file with a database. Need help!
Thanks in advance!

[image: db.php file error]

Comment: Well, putting special characters into a PHP string literal might mean that you have to escape those special characters in some way. Without seeing details, we can’t give more specific advice on that.

Comment: Rather than having the constants with the value you enter, why not call them SERVERNAME, USERNAME etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `"` or `'` for variables.

If you have `$` in your password, you must use `'`.

Like this:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'YOU';
$password = 'BLA BLA';
$db = 'Test_DB';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all the values are String Parameter please provide them with in double quotes, e.g.

```
$servername="localhost";
```